# Automating Settings.py Selection For Local and Prod

Tags: django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a two `settings.py` files: `local.py` and `prod.py`. As the names suggest, `local.py` is used for development and `prod.py` should be used when the server is deployed (which I am doing through EBS).

Is there anyway to **automate this**, instead of swapping them in and out myself? **How can I detect that I am running locally, vs. running on an EBS instance?** Thanks!

Comment: Is EBS like Heroku in the way that you push a git repo to deploy?

Comment: @MartínSchere kind of. It functions like git in that I can have `.gitignores` and stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways how this can be achieved.

One way would be through [.ebextensions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html). The config files in the `.ebextensions` are executed during deployment of your application to EB. Thus you could use, e.g., [commands](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-commands) config files to **automatically provide** the correct config file.

Other way would be to use [EB Environment properties](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-softwaresettings.html) which can be specified in your EB through console, or better using [aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-elasticbeanstalkapplicationenvironment) in `.ebextensions`. Then your application would check the value  (or its existence) of the  environment variable to decide which config file to load.